# Warning building in Sublime Text XeLaTeX BibLaTeX

Tags: biblatex, xetex, sublime-text

I'm having quite some unpleasant moments every time I build my LaTeX documents using Sublime Text 3. Every time I compile a document I get the following warning

> LaTeX Warning: You have requested, on input line 37, version               `2018/01/30' of package pdftexcmds,               but only version`               2018/01/21 v0.26 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)'               is available.

(Yes. pdftexcmds)

The weird part is that this happens even when I have nothing in line 37. AND, when I manually go to the command pallete and select Build with: Latex- Basic Builder Xelatex: the code runs and prints the references as expected (I still get a warning though).

How to avoid this warning in the future?
What is the incompatibility between Xelatex and BibLaTeX?
What is this warning about?  I have no clue how to solve this.

The toy code is:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=55pt]{geometry}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,sorting=nyt,backend=biber]{biblatex}
    \addbibresource{D:/Thesis/ref_thesis.bib}
\begin{document}
Hallo Friends, it happens that \parencite{hausman1} said X but \parencite{athey} said Y.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: codebeforemanually]

[image: aftermanuallybuild]

Comment: My guess would be that you get the warning because the command (or setting) you use has been updated (i.e. you "request" a certain version) while you have an older version. Have you tried updating your packages? Also, sometimes I find that error messages "spill over", so that it might say that the error is in line 37 but there is nothing there because that is not where the error happened exactly but rather where Latex gave up or realised that something happened it wasn't expecting.

Answer (score 1):

The line 37 in the message refers to line 37 in `biblatex.sty`, which is [(in version 3.15a)](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/e5d6e69e61613cc33ab1fcc2083a8277eb9cfce5/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.sty#L37)

```
\RequirePackage{pdftexcmds}[2018/01/30]
```

and thus requests at least version 2018/01/30 of the `pdftexcmds` package.

Your system only has a slightly older version v0.26 from 2018/01/21 of `pdftexcmds`, so you get this warning.

You may want to consider updating your system ([How do I update my TeX distribution?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55437/35864)). If you are using a MikTeX system make sure to run the updater in Admin *and* User mode ([How should one maintain and update a MiKTeX installation?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/108447/35864)).

---

This is not a general incompatibility between `biblatex` and XeLaTeX. It is an incompatibility between your old version of `pdftexcmds` and your newer version of `biblatex`.